# Failure to bind StringElement.Visible to boolean property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

In my Xamarin Studio project on Mac, I am using MvvmCross version 3.0.13 from [MvvmCross-Binaries](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Binaries), the *XS-iOS-Mac Release* assemblies, and I am trying to couple my *CrossUI Dialog* based *View* with a corresponding *ViewModel*. Specifically, I define the `Root` in my dialog view like this:

```
var bindings = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<ViewModel>();
Root = new RootElement("New Connection") {
  new Section {
    new StringElement("Test")
      .Bind(bindings, element => (object)element.SelectedCommand, vm => vm.TestConnection)
  },
  new Section {
    new StringElement ("Add")
      .Bind (bindings, element => element.Visible, vm => vm.CanAddConnection)
      .Bind (bindings, element => (object)element.SelectedCommand, vm => vm.AddConnection)
  }
};
```

In the *ViewModel*, `CanAddConnection` is set to `true` by the `TestConnection` command if test is successful.

When I run this (in the iOS Simulator) and open the dialog, the **Test** button is displayed and the **Add** button is hidden (as intended). When I click the button and the test is successful, the **Add** button is however not displayed, but instead I get this message in the application output:

> How did this happen - CurrentAttachedCell is a child of a non-UITableView

*Why is my Visible binding not working?*

---

As far as I can tell, I have not made any code customizations upstream that would lead to [this failure](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossUI/CrossUI.Touch/Dialog/Elements/Element.cs#L99) in the code (but I might be missing something).

If I bind `CanAddConnection` to another element property, for example `Caption`, the boolean value is properly updated in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably falling foul of an ios7 change which is addressed as part of https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/467

This fix will be included in 3.0.14 (hopefully in the next week) - in the meantime, the easiest workaround is probably to patch `UpdateVisibility` yourself in your own build - or to implement a custom StringElement

Comment: I actually located that page earlier myself when googling on this issue, but I could not immediately realize that it related to my problem. For the time being, I'll be better off waiting for the 3.0.14 release rather that setting up and building patch assemblies, but many thanks anyway, @Stuart, for helping me sort out this issue.